# How to fix error to add prefix and suffix to certain set of numbers from a text file

Tags: perl

How to add prefix and suffix to a set of numbers obtained from a text file. I have written the coding but it's showing some bugs.

My text file contain numbers like

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and the output should come like

```
                                3r_1.pdb
                                3r_2.pdb
                                .
                                .
                                3r_6.pdb
```

The program:-

```
open(FILE,"text.txt");
open(OUT,">output.txt");
while($file=<FILE>)
{
$f= "3r_";
$e= ".pdb";
chomp($file);
print OUT "$f$file$e\n";

}
```

I am unable to understand where the bug is actually.

Comment: What's wrong with your program? It looks like it should work, except that it doesn't put spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: You should definitely check that the `open` calls succeed: `open FILE, "text.txt" or die "Failed to open file text.txt for reading ($!)";` etc.  You should preferably use lexical file handles and the 3-argument `open`, as in `open my $FILE, '<', "text.txt" or die "A horrible death";` and then use `$FILE` in place of `FILE`.  You should also `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and declare the variables with `my`.  However, apart from error checking `open`, the code looks 'good to go' and when I test it, it works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pattern is the same here is how I would do it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $in, "<", "text.txt") or die $!;
open(my $out, ">", "output.txt") or die $!;

while (my $line = <$in>)
{
  chomp ($line);
  print $out "3r_" . $line . ".pdb\n";
}

close ($in);
close ($out);
```

You should always `use strict; use warnings;`.  With modern Perl, it is best practice to use the three-argument open for files as well.  It is more clear and lets the program be more efficient.

Comment: Why do you need to use the `.` operator? Perl has supported variable interpolation in strings for as long as I can remember (over 20 years).

Comment: About the only time I use the `.` operator is when I need to concatenate a function call with other material, and even then, I more normally save the result into a variable and interpolate the variable into a string, exactly as in the question.

Comment: @Barmar Fair, I deleted that note.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    print "3r_$_.pdb\n";
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl text.txt >output.txt`

This lets Perl handle the file i/o, i.e., you don't need to `open` or `close` any files.  Each line in *text.txt* is read and `chomp`ed.  Perl's default scalar `$_` is used to create the final file names.